# On Map CheckBox Event not working when checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

- i created Text lable & one check box on map in java script

//initialized map....

// code for creating text & lable;

```
var optionControlDiv = document.createElement('div');
    optionControlDiv.id='options';
 var optionControl = new OptionControl(optionControlDiv, map);
    optionControlDiv.index = 1;
map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT].push(optionControlDiv); 
var optionControlDivText = document.createElement('div');
    optionControlDivText.id='optionss';
var optionControlText = new OptionControlText(optionControlDivText, map);
    optionControlDivText.index = 2;
map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT].push(optionControlDivText);
```

//calling functions of lable & checkbox

```
function OptionControl(controlDiv, map) {
controlDiv.style.padding = '5px';
controlDiv.style.right = '90px';
var controlUI = document.createElement('input');
controlUI.type="checkbox";
controlUI.id="arrowcheck";
google.maps.event.addDomListener(controlUI,'click',function(){
checkboxclicked();
 // alert($('#arrowcheck').is(':checked'));
   });    
controlDiv.appendChild(controlUI); 

}
function OptionControlText(controlDiv, map) {
controlDiv.style.padding = '8px';
controlDiv.style.right = '111px';
var controlUI = document.createElement('label');
controlUI.type="label";
controlUI.innerHTML="Lable";
controlDiv.appendChild(controlUI); 
}
```

i am calling checkboxclicked() when i clicked on checkbox

```
 function checkboxclicked()
  {

  alert($('#arrowcheck').is(':checked')); // its shows flase when i checked

  }
```

- when i checked its showing false & when i un-cheked its shows true
- please help for if written wrong code.

Comment: you want to get checkbox check event?

Comment: yes.when i click checkbox will get alert as true,if un-check alert will get false.. but i will get reverse order(above code).

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
$(".checkbox").change(function() {
    if(this.checked) {
        //Do stuff
    }
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ashuslove/HkEuf/2519/)

Comment: check the demo i have used alert in check event of checkbox